# sails.js socket lifetime. is unsubscription necessary?

Tags: sockets, sails.js, lifetime

My sails application returns mostly rendered views. I'm not using any client side front end js framework so it doesn't make sense for it to return JSON or XML. In my view, I have this js.

```
io.socket.get
(
    location.pathname,
    function(model)
    {
        if(typeof model !== 'undefined' && typeof model.error === 'undefined' && model !== null && model)
        {
            io.socket.on
            (
                model,
                function(event)
                {
                    console.log(event);
                }
            );
        }
    }
);
```

My controllers aren't strictly mapped to a model. It's kind of spaghetti coding but I don't know how else to do it. A restaurant contains point of sales machines(POS). In my restaurant controller, I have

```
    detail: function(req, res)
    {
        Restaurant.findOne
        (
            {
                where:
                {
                    owner: req.session.owner.id,
                    id: req.params.id
                }
            }
        )
        .populate('POSs')
        .exec
        (
            function(err, restaurant)
            {
                if(err)
                {
                    res.serverError(err);
                }
                else if(typeof restaurant === 'undefined')
                {
                    res.notFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    Restaurant.count
                    (
                        {
                            owner: req.session.owner.id
                        }
                    )
                    .exec
                    (
                        function(err, num)
                        {
                            console.log(req.socket.id);
                            if(req.isSocket)
                            {
                                POS.subscribe(req.socket, restaurant.POSs);
                                res.send('pos');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                res.view({restaurant: restaurant, count: num});
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Now the question is do I need to unsubscribe? If I go away from the page, it appears I will have a different socket id. Will the server still think the old socket is still subscribed and push messages to that old socket? Ie if I go to the path that triggers the 'detail' path in the restaurant controller, refresh, and do an ajax request that triggers `POS.publishUpdate(pos.id, {status: pos.status});` from another controller, will sails need to notify two sockets even if there is only one current socket that's still alive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some investigating, I opened up config/sockets.js and saw the `onConnect` and `onDisconnect` function. I added some logging to it and have determined on page refresh, the socket gets disconnected anyways. Therefore, it's safe to assume that unsubscription is unnecessary